# Question about vitakka and vicara. How to reinforce upper jhanas (without vitakka and vicara)

Tags: mindfulness, jhana

Sometimes i am keeping some mental object in mind, free from anger or greed, and for a moment i feel piti and sukha over my entire body. Sometimes this piti and sukha keep with me for a long time.

But even in first jhana i keep my mental object in mind, like blue kasina (whondering world all blue) or parts of body.

Sometimes the piti and sukha leaves.

I read that after the first jhana we need to abandon the vitakka and vicara. But how?

I need to keep my focus in some mental object or just let the things go at their own pace, in my mind.

How to i reinforce the upper jhanas if i need to abandon the mental objects?

Ps: sometimes i feel piti and sukha, when concentrate into the kammathana, both in public and in my cave (bedroom).

Comment: Hello, there are plenty of answers on here specifically about the second jhana, please use the search feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that after the first jhana we need to abandon the vitakka and vicara. But how?

The practice you're doing, is based on Vism. and their redefinition of jhāna, vitakka, etc.
If you want to follow the Buddha's definition of jhāna, then you have to follow the buddha's definition of vitakka so you know what V&V is in first jhāna and what you are removing to enter second jhāna, as described here: (my collection of notes, contains links to all the sutta passages that use vitakka in jhāna context)
https://lucid24.org/sted/8aam/8samadhi/vitakka/index.html

If you prefer to follow the LBT (late buddhist teaching) redefinition of 'jhāna', then just keep doing what you're doing, and it will improve naturally. They redefine 'vitakka' and vicāra as the subverbal attention on your kasina. As you become skilled in staying on the kasina with very little effort or resistance, that's the gradual  removal of V&V. Vicāra is redefined as keeping your attention focused on the kasina. "second jhāna" with V&V removed is redefined to mean you no longer had to exert so much force and energy to keep your mind from drifting away from the kasina.

Answer (score -1):

Leave house first, as higher Dhamma isn't taught to householder by Noble Ones and what's the use of blind teaching blind, good householder.

Holding on house they just have the stand: there is no house, or there is, caught in this or that view, extreme, incapable of even understand kāya. So penetrating through house opens the path, yet who could if not even aware of it. No Saddha (no surrender), no path but just any certain stand, even Jhana is taken as a stand by those not surrender.

Doubters (on house/stand-holders) might give (already gave) of course 'smart' answers, good householder, so nothing to worry.

Answer (score -2):

There is no awareness of the physical body in jhana. In MN 119, the word 'kaya' does not refer exclusively to the physical body.

Also, piti & sukha do not cease in the 1st and 2nd jhanas.

Also, there are different degrees & levels of piti & sukha therefore not all piti & sukha are factors of jhana.

The Buddha taught jhana is reached by making 'letting go' or 'surrender' ('vossagga') the meditation object ([SN 48.10](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN48_10.html)). Therefore, willfully asserting the mind upon a meditation object is not related to jhana.

Vitakka & vicara in jhana does not mean 'ordinary thinking'. Instead, in jhana, vitakka & vicara are subtle movements of the mind drawn towards the piti & sukkha. Vitakka & vicara end in the 2nd jhana by the mind itself directly seeing the non-peacefulness of vitakka & vicara. Thus the suttas say the 2nd jhana is "born from concentration" ("samādhijaṁ").

In summary, vitakka & vicara do not create jhana or make jhana more firm. Instead, vitakka & vicara are like obstacles or impurities in jhana.

In conclusion, jhana is free from the five hindrances, which includes 'doubt'. Minds that have reached real jhana are totally free from doubt about it therefore don't ask questions about jhana on internet forums.

Comment: Except that doubt will rearise once the conditions of jhana have passed.  If there wasn't rearising, then even the first jhana would be anuttara samyak sambodhi.  The first paragraphs are correct, the last isn't Buddhism.

Comment: @asd123 thanks for the elucidation

Comment: @Dhammadhatu in spite of you discourage people for questioning about jhana, you have an answer from another question that brought light to my mind. Thank you so much

Comment: no. doubt will not rearise when jhana has passed. For example, the Buddha did not always abide in jhana yet obviously the Buddha was totally free from doubt.

Comment: Right, because he had eradicated that obstacle with insight.  Just because one attains jhana does not mean that doubt, et all are permanently eradicated.  If that were the case, the Buddha would have become the Buddha as a baby under the rose apple tree.

Comment: Show the sutta passages  that define vitakka and vicara you described.

Comment: Show the sutta passages that define vitakka and vicara as you described. –